# T-SQL, joining two tables between an integer column in the first table and a comma separated string column in the other

Tags: string, join

I have a situation like this (T-SQL):

Table 1: dbo.Printers

```
EmulationID              EmulationDescription              PrinterID         Name

34,15,2                  NULL                              12                HP 1234 
15,2                     NULL                              13                IBM 321 
15                       NULL                              14                XYZ
```

Table 2: dbo.Emulations

```
EmulationID              Description

34                       HP
15                       IBM
2                        Dell
```

EmulationID column in dbo.Printers table is nvarchar/unicode string datatype, and integer datatype in the dbo.Emulations table.

Now I have to **UPDATE** the ****EmulationDescription**** column in the dbo.Printers table using a lookup on the dbo.Emulations table through the EmulationID column.

I need to get data like this in the dbo.Printers table:

```
EmulationID              EmulationDescription              PrinterID         Name

34,15,2                  HP,IBM,Dell                       12                HP 1234 
15,2                     IBM,Dell                          13                IBM 321 
15                       IBM                               14                XYZ
```

Can someone help me in detail, on how to get this issue resolved ?

I created the user-defined function dbo.ParseIdListToTable to convert string data in one row into multiple rows. However, I do not know to proceed further, on how to exactly join and then update.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: clean your question, separate codes, align tables to look like a table. this way people will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CSVToTable] (@InStr VARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS @TempTab TABLE
       (id int not null)
    AS
    BEGIN
        ;-- Ensure input ends with comma
        SET @InStr = REPLACE(@InStr + ',', ',,', ',')
        DECLARE @SP INT
    DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
    WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
    BEGIN
       SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%,%',@INSTR)
       SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
       SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
       INSERT INTO @TempTab(id) VALUES (@VALUE)
    END
        RETURN
    END
    GO


DECLARE @Description VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT P.EmulationID,
    (SELECT  @Description = COALESCE(@Description + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(Description)
    FROM    dbo.Emulations
    WHERE EmulationID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(P.EmulationID))) AS 'Emulation Description,
P.PrinterID,
P.Name
FROM dbo.Printers P
```

Comment: I was trying to use this code with some modification (the unicode string to datatype conversion fails)

Comment: UPDATE dbo.Printers
SET dbo.Printers.EmulationDescription = dbo.Emulations.[Description]
FROM dbo.Printers
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Emulations
ON dbo.Printers.EmulationId = dbo.Emulations.EmulationId

Comment: I am getting 2 syntax errors after @Description is declared:  near = COALESCE  , and another near ) towards the end;

Comment: I am getting 2 syntax errors after @Description is declared:  near   =COALESCE  , and another near ) towards the end;  ; can you kindly guide me with exact syntaxes ? It looks like there is something wrong near the subquery execution